# In Python, I would like to read a huge CSV file stored in a zip file, but only a fixed sized chunk at a time

Tags: python, csv, zip

I am working with a 468 MB zip file that contains a single file, which is a CSV text file.  I don't want to extract the **entire** text file, so I read the zip file a binary chunk at a time.  The chunk size is something like 65536 bytes.

I know I can read the file with Python's **csvfile** library, but in this case, the chunks that I feed it will not necessarily fall on a line boundary.

How can I do this?  (p.s., I do not want to have to use ***Pandas***)

Thanks.

Comment: I believe the `ZipFile` module allows you to create a stream to the zip file. You can then use this in `csv.reader()`. It won't read the entire thing into memory.

Comment: @Barmar yeah that would definitely work, except it might only be a binary stream...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to do something like:

```
import zipfile
import io
import csv


with zipfile.ZipFile("test.zip") as zipf:
    with zipf.open("test.csv", "r") as f:
        reader = csv.reader(
            io.TextIOWrapper(f, newline='')
        )
        for row in reader:
            do_something(row)
```

Assuming you have a zip archive like:

```
jarrivillaga$ unzip -l test.zip
Archive:  test.zip
  Length      Date    Time    Name
---------  ---------- -----   ----
1308888890  04-01-2022 16:23   test.csv
---------                     -------
1308888890                     1 file
```

Note, the `zipf.open` returns a binary stream, so you can just use an `io.TextIOWrapper` to make it a text stream, which would work with any of the `csv.reader` or `csv.DictReader` objects.

This should read it in reasonably sized chunks by default, probably whatever `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is, because looking at the `zipfile.ZipExtFile` source code it is inheriting from `io.BufferedIOBase`.

Comment: The binary stream itself should be fine without a `TextIOWrapper` because a `csv.reader` (normally) wants a file opened with `newline=""`.

Comment: Yes, this works!  I had to fiddle with the encoding and delimiter, but it works.  Thanks!

Comment: @martineau no, `csv` reader types expect a text stream since Python 3, they don't accept bytes

Comment: @martineau but good point about `newline=''`!